# CSS Loading animation on whole page with opacity

Tags: javascript, css

This is CSS animation which i want to use.
Here is what i got:

```css
.img {
 width:300px;
 height:100%;
}
.loading {
 content ="Loading";
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: PT Sans Narrow;

  font-size: 30px;
   top: 45%;
   left: 45%;
   
  position: absolute;
}

.loading:after {
  
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-animation: ellipsis steps(5,end) 1000ms infinite;      
  animation: ellipsis steps(5,end) 1000ms infinite;
  content: "\2026\2026"; /* ascii code for the ellipsis character */
  width: 0px;
}

@keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 1.15em;    
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 1.5em;    
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="loading">Loading</div>

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iQUErgs.png" class="img"></img>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iQUErgs.png" class="img"></img>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iQUErgs.png" class="img"></img>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iQUErgs.png" class="img"></img>
</html>
```

Currently background is not covered while images are loading and it is a goal.
I tried using content property but it is not really working out for me.

What i am trying to achive is loading screen with centered text when all images are loading and screen covered in transparent grey/black.

I need loading screen when images are actually loading.

Answer (score 4):

I have added the follow to your code in `.loading`:

```
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

`position: fixed` allows the element to float in view while scrolling. `top` and `left` align the fixed element to the top left corner. To align the text to the center I used `flex`. Read more on flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). `align-items: center` vertically aligns all elements in a flexbox elements. `justify-content: center` does the same, except horizontally.

```css
.img {
 width:300px;
 height:100%;
}
.loading {
  content ="Loading";
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: PT Sans Narrow;

  font-size: 30px;
   
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.loading:after {
  
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-animation: ellipsis steps(5,end) 1000ms infinite;      
  animation: ellipsis steps(5,end) 1000ms infinite;
  content: "\2026\2026"; /* ascii code for the ellipsis character */
  width: 0px;
}

@keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 1.15em;    
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 1.5em;    
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="loading">Loading</div>

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iQUErgs.png" class="img"></img>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iQUErgs.png" class="img"></img>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iQUErgs.png" class="img"></img>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iQUErgs.png" class="img"></img>
</html>
```